# How do I read data line by line in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, file-io, io

I am new to Ruby and am creating a Poker game application. I am trying to read in each player's cards from a text file. The data in the text file looks like this:

```
8C TS KC 9H 4S 7D 2S 5D 3S AC
5C AD 5D AC 9C 7C 5H 8D TD KS
3H 7H 6S KC JS QH TD JC 2D 8S
```

and so forth. The first 5 on each line are one player's cards, and the other 5 the other's. How would I go about reading in this data? I have already written a Card class that can create cards based on how they are represented in the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
IO.foreach('cards.txt') do |line|
  cards = line.chomp.split.map { |c| Card.new(c) }
  hand1 = cards[0, 5]
  hand2 = cards[5, 5]
  #...
end
```

or...

```
handpairs = File.open('cards.txt') do |f|
  f.each_line.map { |line|
    line.chomp.split.each_slice(5).map { |cs|
      cs.map { |c| Card.new(c) }
    }
  }
end
```

Comment: I was part-way into an answer but you pretty much nailed it. My only point of difference, you could do `line.chomp.split.map(&Card.method(:new)).each_slice(5)` too.

Comment: @Kimball: Not Python, TIMTOWTDI :)